# Cannot spawn In-Scene (Placed) NetworkObjects on client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I read this Doc: [unityDoc](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/scenemanagement/inscene-placed-networkobjects/)

I have a game with two Players. I host on one and the other one is the client. Both Players Spawn and move... .
I want to synchronize the Animation of a Door on the Host and Client.
I add the door to the scene without a Network Object child.
On both, the client and Host the doors spawned and i can interact to open them.

Now when I add a Network Object to the door it spawns on the host but the client gets this Error:

`[Netcode] Failed to spawn NetworkObject for Hash 540901771.`
`[Netcode] Failed to create object locally. [globalObjectIdHash=540901771]. NetworkPrefab could not be found. Is the prefab registered with NetworkManager?`

I registered the prefab in the NetworkManager.
I tried some other empty objects with just a Network Object and I get the same error.

I really don't understand what the problem is.

I am using
Unity 2022.3.11f1
Netcode for GameObjects v1.6.0

I did a workaround where I spawn the door in a script that gets spawned with the Player Prefabs.
It works, but I will have more doors with different positions.
Also I don't think its a good way to do it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. The "Enable Scene Management" in the NetworkManager has to be enabeld.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for other people: make sure all of the scripts on the networkobject inherit from NetworkBehaivor, and make sure all of the objects you spawn are added to the networkprefablist. (No idea what's wrong with mine, since I tried those, and also the "Enable Scene Management" is already enabled... I'm still getting the errors.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!